# Allow a mixture of " and ' in a PHP string without closing the variable

Tags: php, html, string, htmlpurifier

i am allowing users to submit data into my website.

This data will more than likely contain html markup generated by forums. The problem is, some forums use "" for some attributes and then use '' for others.

If the user enters this, it will break my PHP code as i assign this entered text to a variable.

I am using HTMLPurifier on this string.

Is there a way to allow a mixture of "' inside a php string?

e.g:

```
$text = "This is an image <img src='imagelink' alt="imagetext">";
```

Wouldn't work. But its what i receive sometimes.

Whilst im at it, what is the correct term for " & ' when giving a value to a attribute?

Craig.

Comment: _“If the user enters this, it will break my PHP code as i assign this entered text to a variable”_ – that will break nothing, if you just assign the value to a variable at runtime. It’s a different matter however, if you dynamically create PHP-_Code_ from that user input – which you __should not do__ anyways, because they might enter more than just text – function calls, etc.

Comment: Double quotes vs. single quotes would be the "technical" (not-very-technical) term. As @Fluffeh's answer says, all you need to do is escape the quote with `\'` or `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can delimit the quotes inside the variable like this:

```
$text = "This is an image <img src='imagelink' alt=\"imagetext\">";
```

Which will then do what you need.

I am not sure how this HTMLPurifier thingy works, but with this delimiting trick up your sleeve, I am confident that you can find a way to stop folks breaking your variables :)

Edit: As for your little additional question:

> Whilst im at it, what is the correct term for " & ' when giving a value to a attribute?

I think you are referring to [passing by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). It means when you pass a variable to a function, you aren't just passing it's value, but the actual variable itself which can be modified and then returned.

```
<?php
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a=5;
foo($a);
// $a is 6 here
?>
```

Comment: Second questions is referring to the correct way to give value to an attribute... `alt="Hello"` or `alt='hello'`... but technically there is no difference... both are valid